Output Capacitor of Buck Converter
EXPLANATION
Picture 1 shows the power stages of the buck converter.
Position 1, the node equation is ic= iL-V/R
Position 2, the node equation is ic= iL-V/R
The same node equation exists for both positions. That is okay.

As seen in Picture 2,
The capacitor is actually charged/discharged from 0 to DTs which is the Position 1. That means that During Period 1, I need to have 2 equation (1 for charge and 1 for disharge) so that I can find the slopes of Vc.
On the other hand it is charged/discharged from DTs to Ts (D'Ts) which is the Position 2. That means that During Period 2, I need to have 2 equation (1 for charge and 1 for disharge) so that I can find the slopes of Vc.
QUESTION
Everywhere it is treated as if there is a single node equation for period 1 and 2, why ?  another way to say, it is treated as the capacitor is only charged in both Positions, but actually it is not.
In Picture 3 I illustrated what I mean. To calculate charge balance  the only equation used in Picture 3 is again ic= iL-V/R (indicates capacitor is charging) in both positions. Why? there is a discharge also in both Positions. This is the point that makes me confused.
Picture 1 : Buck converter

Source: https://elprivod.nmu.org.ua/files/converters/Robert_Erikson_fundamentals-of-power-electronics-3n_2020.pdf
Picture 2 : Inductor and capacitor wave forms

Source= My drawing

Source: https://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dcostine/ECE481/Fall2017/lectures/L3_out.pdf

Please edit your question to say on which of the thousand pages of book that you've linked to those figures show up.

Mhan, are we done here?

Mhan, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

\$I_C = I_L - \frac{V_O}{R_L}\$

If \$I_L\$ is greater than the load current (\$\frac{V_O}{R_L}\$) then the capacitor is charged
If \$I_L\$ is less than the load current (\$\frac{V_O}{R_L}\$) then the capacitor is being discharged.

That's what the formula tells you. And from knowledge of buck convertors, at the start of position 1, \$I_L\$ is indeed less than \$\frac{V_O}{R_L}\$ but, at the end of position 1 \$I_L\$ is greater than \$\frac{V_O}{R_L}\$ and the capacitor will be receiving charge.


Everywhere it is treated as if there is a single node equation for period 1 and 2, why ?

I assume you mean that the standard treatment is that there is one set of equations in position 1, and a different set in position two.
Because until you start to care about what happens when your switching element actually switches that's a pretty good model.

Another way to say, it is treated as the capacitor is only charged in both Positions, but actually it is not.

The capacitor charging through the entire half-switch interval in either position 1 or position 2 is not implied by the fact that the effective circuit does not change.  It's exactly as you've discovered: in order to maintain constant output voltage, as the inductor current changes the capacitor must alternately source and sink current.  If that wasn't happening, it'd be a good indication that the capacitor wasn't needed.

Thank you, but what I am asking and what you are answering. I think you didnt understand my question  @TimWescott

I am again explaining again for you, If the capacitor is charged and discharged in half switch intervals (Position 1 and Position 2, see Picture 2), why there is only 1 node equation which is ic= iL-V/R. This equation tells that capacitor is only charged in both positions ( see Picture 3, the node equations are same ) if so why is Why does the discharge of the capacitor not include in the calculations? or why do we treat the capacitor is charged only for both positions ?  @TimWescott
